# Random numbers and temp tables in SQL

Tags: sql, random, vertica

I have a problem with using random numbers together with temp tables. I have a table from which I want to select some random `user_id`'s and then in the second table select some more, but with no repetition from the first one. A quick example follows (it is simplified, so pls don't write to simply select `user_id`s in the first place):

```
drop table if exists test; 

create table test (
user_id int,
g int);

insert into test values (1, 1);
insert into test values (2, 1);
insert into test values (3, 1);
insert into test values (4, 1);
insert into test values (5, 1);
insert into test values (6, 1);

with temp as (
select t.user_id
from (select tt.*, row_number() over (partition by tt.g order by randomint(100)) as seqnum
      from test tt) t 
where t.seqnum <= 2
)
select user_id from temp union all 
select user_id from test where user_id not in (select user_id from temp)
```

The result of the query shoul ideally return all `user_id`s, however, it results in an incomplete set but with repetitions. Do you know how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two different methods for processing CTEs.  One method stores the CTE in a temporary table, so the code is only executed once regardless of the number of references.

The second method is to incorporate the CTE code into the query, so the code may be run more than one time.

As far as I know, the ANSI standard does not specify which method to use and different databases use different methods -- some even choose between the two using the optimizer.

Vertica would seem to use the second method (this is speculation based on your results, not something that I know for sure for Vertica).  As a result, the second reference to `temp` is recalculated -- resulting in the results you see.

What can you do?

One thing would be to use a "random" number generator that will return the same values.  To be honest, that might not work on a larger table in Vertica due to parallelization and timing.  But, providing a seed might help.

A similar alternative is to use something like "row_number * 17 - 39 mod 101".  If the `row_number()` value uses a stable sort, then this will return the same rows each time.

Another approach is to store the results in a temporary table.

Finally, there might be a compiler option instructing Vertica to materialize the CTE.

Personally, I would use the second method, because I know that it works across multiple databases, but the other methods might work for your particular situation.

EDIT:

```
with temp as (
      select t.*
      from (select t.user_id
                   row_number() over (partition by tt.g order by  mod(71 * seqnum - 31, 101), user_id) as psuedo
            from (select tt.*,
                         row_number() over (partition by tt.g order by user_id) as seqnum
                  from test tt
                 ) t 
           ) t
      where t.pseudo <= 2
     )
```

The `row_number()` is stable -- it should produce the same values every time it is run.  The arithmetic turns this into a pseudo-random number, which is then turned into another sequence.  This approach is often good enough.  You can adjust the prime numbers to change values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Gordon! Could you please show me what you mean with this second approach, meaning should I input `row_number() * 17 - mod(39, 101)` as seqnum?

Answer (score 2):

It is a problem with CTEs in some backends (MS SQL server has the same problem too for example). I don't use Vertica, if it supports temp tables then an easy and non-cryptic solution would be to select the initial into a temp table rather then into a CTE. Sample with MS SQL server would look like:

```
CREATE TABLE #test (user_id INT, g INT);

INSERT INTO #test VALUES(1, 1);
INSERT INTO #test VALUES(2, 1);
INSERT INTO #test VALUES(3, 1);
INSERT INTO #test VALUES(4, 1);
INSERT INTO #test VALUES(5, 1);
INSERT INTO #test VALUES(6, 1);

SELECT TOP(2) * INTO #temp FROM #test ORDER BY NEWID();

SELECT user_id FROM #temp
UNION ALL
SELECT user_id FROM #test WHERE user_id NOT IN(SELECT user_id FROM #temp);

DROP TABLE #test;
DROP TABLE #temp;
```

Comment: I tried both answers and they work fine, thanks for help @Cetin!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hint to force Vertica to materialize the WITH clause. 

`WITH /*+ENABLE_WITH_CLAUSE_MATERIALIZATION*/ with-query...`

For more information, including on how to set this on a session level rather than per query with a hint, see https://my.vertica.com/docs/9.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/AnalyzingData/Queries/Subqueries/WithClauseMaterialization.htm